Why can't I narrow types using property null checking?
Why can't I use property checking to narrow the type like so?
function test2(value:{a:number}|{b:number}){
    // `.a` underlined with: "Property a does not exist on type {b:number}"
    if(value.a != null){
        console.log('value of a:',value.a)
    }
}

test2({a:1})

test2({b:2})


It transpiles fine, works as designed, and throws no runtime errors. The property check logically narrows the scope to {a:number}.
So what's wrong with this?
Is there a setting I can change to make it allow and use this method of type narrowing?
Someone will probably tell me to use the in operator. So I suppose I'll say now that I know I could use the in operator, but I don't want to. If I union the type with string as well, then I can't use in with string and I have to first check to make sure it's not a string with if(typeof value != 'string'), but in regular JavasScript I could simply leave my property check and know that whatever I get will have the property and all will be well.
So, what's the problem with TypeScript here? Is it just not smart enough to figure it out?
(Changes: This question was originally about optional chaining to check for properties because the type was unioned with a null as well, but to simplify the question I've removed the null and the optional chain operator from the if statement.)

?. handles the left-hand side being null or undefined; given the argument isn't optional, it's no safer than value.a.

Actually, this doesn't have anything to do with optional chaining because your parameter type ensures an incoming argument can't be nullish anyway.

@Behemoth Ah, originally I had it unioned with null... Thanks for pointing that out. Let me change the question a bit.

This kind of narrowing is not (yet) supported in TypesScript. There are issues such as microsoft/TypeScript#42384 that address this problem. As of now the only way to narrow object unions by their properties is by narrowing the discriminant of a discriminated union. Does that answer your question?

@Behemoth That does really enlighten me on things. Thank you. I think your answer, combined with Bergi's is a complete answer.


what's the problem with TypeScript here?

It just points out diligently that your code is accessing a property that is not declared to exist on the object. If it wasn't a union type, you'd expect to get this error message. That the code doesn't throw a runtime error doesn't mean that it's valid TypeScript.
If you insist on accessing the property to discriminate the union, you'll have to declare it on all type constituents - you still can declare it to have no value on the others:
function test2(value: { a: number; b?: never } | { b: number; a?: never }){
    if(value.a != null) {
        console.log('value of a:', value.a)
    }
}

test2({a:1})
test2({b:2})


"It just points out diligently that your code is accessing a property that is not declared to exist on the object." So is it an error or a warning? Could it just be a warning?

Also, why does typescript not know at the line with the console print, that the a property on value must exist now, because it too is underlined, but it's obvious that it does exist at this point, whatever the type may be.

@ADJenks valid question. The property does exist at that point (proof). Bergi probably just didn't remove the comment from your example.

Oh right, it would be fine in Bergi's answer, but would not the property exist in my example by the console line as well? Since the property is checked for in the preceding line?

@ADJenks Every type error (as opposed to a syntax error) is "just a warning", TypeScript can still compile it to JavaScript. But there is no distinction between "bad" and "ok" type check failures (other than that you can turn some of them off with compiler flags, but there is none for accessing non-existing properties afaik).

@ADJenks As to why it still underlines the second occurrence of the property access, it's probably just that the failed type check in the condition does not lead to a successful narrowing of the type for value.

There's another more verbose way, where you won't need to declare the same properties on each type.   We can use a type predicator which runs a check on the object that is passed to it and if that object passes those tests it is safely determined to be the type you want.
type A = {
  a: number;
};

type B = {
  b: number;
};

function isA(arg: unknown): arg is A {
  return !!arg && typeof arg === "object" && "a" in arg;
}

function isB(arg: unknown): arg is B {
  return !!arg && typeof arg === "object" && "b" in arg;
}

function test2(value: A | B) {
  if (isA(value)) {
    console.log("value of a:", value.a);
  }
  if (isB(value)) {
    console.log("Vale of b:", value.b);
  }
}

test2({ a: 1 });
test2({ b: 2 });

isA and isB are predicators that let TS know checks have been made and the type is as we expect.  Predicators are not foolproof, as we could simply return true from a predicator effectively be lying to typescript.  But predicators are powerful tools when you can be handling unique types that can't be discriminated due to similar properties.
Here is a playground demoing the above code. https://tsplay.dev/WJ0KZN  ...and some light reading on type predicates in the TS docs.. https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates

This is where using the discriminated union pattern would have been helpful. The idea is to add a field which has a unique value into each interface, thus making it possible to disambiguate the correct type when used in a union situation.
Example:
type NetworkLoadingState = {
  state: "loading";
};
type NetworkFailedState = {
  state: "failed";
  code: number;
};
type NetworkSuccessState = {
  state: "success";
  response: {
    title: string;
    duration: number;
    summary: string;
  };
};

type NetworkState =
  | NetworkLoadingState
  | NetworkFailedState
  | NetworkSuccessState;

function onNetworkStateChanged(network: NetworkState) {
  switch (network.state) {
    case "loading":
      console.log("Loading state...")
      break;
    case "failed":
      console.log("Network failed to load. Error code:", network.code);
      break;
    case "success":
      console.log(`Network is connected! Time taken: ${network.response.duration / 1000} seconds`);
      break;
  }
}

Playground link
